# Jetpack-Compose ModalBottomSheetLayout throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException with initial state "Hidden"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

By playing with a ModalBottomSheet in Compose, I get the following issue:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The initial value must have an associated anchor.

My composable function has:

1. a ModalBottomSheetState and a CoroutinScope,
2. a ModalBottomSheetLayout with,
3. a Scaffold as bottom sheet content.

```kotlin
// 1.
val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

// 2. 
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetContent = {
        /* sheetContent */
    },
    sheetState = sheetState,
    // modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize() --> it doesn't change the result
) {
    // 3.
    Scaffold {
        /* scaffold content */
    }
}
```

By setting the initial state of the bottom sheet to ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded, the issue disappears. Note the exception is also thrown for ModalBottomSheetValue.HalfExpanded and without any initial value (the default is Hidden, so it seems logic).

Is there a known workaround or a version of the library where it is working (version of compose I use: 1.0.0 and I tried with 1.0.0-rc2) ?

**UPDATE**

After some investigation, it seems that the issue is due to a dynamic content in the sheet content. I have there a Column/LazyColumn that recomposes when data are available. By having a fixed content, the issue disappear for any ModalBottomSheetValue.

**FIX**

With "null" content (understand a content with a height of 0 dp), the composable function has probably not enough information to compose the modal bottom sheet. It is the case with dynamic column content (starting with no content, so height = 0 dp).

To fix this, set a minimal height of 1 dp somewhere in the sheet content hierarchy:

```
val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetContent = {
        Box(modifier.defaultMinSize(minHeight = 1.dp)) {
            /* sheet content */
        }
    },
    sheetState = sheetState,
    // modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize() --> it doesn't change the result
) {
    Scaffold {
        /* scaffold content */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

With "null" content (understand a content with a height of 0 dp), the composable function has probably not enough information to compose the modal bottom sheet. It is the case with dynamic column content (starting with no content, so height = 0 dp).

To fix this, set a minimal height of 1 dp somewhere in the sheet content hierarchy:

```kotlin
val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetContent = {
        Box(modifier.defaultMinSize(minHeight = 1.dp)) {
            /* sheet content */
        }
    },
    sheetState = sheetState,
    // modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize() --> it doesn't change the result
) {
    Scaffold {
        /* scaffold content */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add `Spacer` in `sheetContent` to avoid above expecption

```
sheetContent = {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(1.dp))
        Box() {
            /* sheet content */
        }
    }
```

Comment: Be careful that if you use a `Spacer`, you need to take its size into account if you add a top padding to the `Box`. By using `defaultMinSize`, you don't need to care of it.

Answer (score 2):

For me the approved solution didn't work.

In my case it was failing when I had a bottomSheet content with an unspecified height (lazyColumn) and I wanted the bottomSheet to wrap the height of the content by using this line when opening it:

```
sheetState.animateTo(ModalBottomSheetValue.HalfExpanded)
```

For me the solution was to wrap the sheetContent with:

```
Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()).
```

I hope this solution can help someone else out, here is the pseudo code:

```
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetContent = {
            Column(modifier.fillMaxSize()) { ------> The solution
                /* sheet content */
            }
        },
        sheetState = sheetState,
       
    ) {
        Scaffold {
            /* scaffold content */
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wrapping the ModalBottomSheetLayout around the scaffold did the magic for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This problem was fixed in version [1.4.0-alpha04](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material#1.4.0-alpha04)

> Fixed an issue where ModalBottomSheetLayout would crash if the sheet content was empty. ModalBottomSheetLayout now allows empty sheet content. If the sheet content is empty, it will only have a Hidden state. (Ic2288, b/200980998, b/216693030)